Unable to Retrieve MessageGroupId from SQS FIFO Queue Messages in Java SDK
[I am working with an AWS SQS FIFO queue and have sent several messages with different MessageGroupIds. However, when I try to retrieve the MessageGroupId from the received messages using the AWS SDK for Java, I am unable to get the value and it returns null.
Here is the code I’m using to receive the messages and attempt to extract the MessageGroupId:
private static final SqsClient sqsClient = SqsClient.builder()
            .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
            .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();
private static final String queueUrl = "fifo_url";
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
                    .queueUrl(queueUrl)
                    .maxNumberOfMessages(10)
                    .waitTimeSeconds(20)
                    .build();
ReceiveMessageResponse response = sqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);
List<Message> messages = response.messages();
for (Message message : messages) {
    Map<MessageSystemAttributeName, String> messageAttributes = message.attributes();
    String messageGroupId = messageAttributes.get("MessageGroupId");
}

In another attempt, I tried accessing the MessageGroupId from the message attributes like this:
private static String getMessageGroupId(Message message) {
        Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> attributes = message.messageAttributes();
        if (attributes != null && attributes.containsKey("MessageGroupId")) {
            return attributes.get("MessageGroupId").stringValue();
        }
        return "No Group ID";  
    }

](https://i.sstatic.net/yP8aBX0w.png)
What I have tried:

I’ve verified that the queue is a FIFO queue.
I have used both message.attributes() and message.messageAttributes() to get the MessageGroupId.
I’ve confirmed that messages were sent with different MessageGroupIds.


You are not requesting SQS to send the message attributes you are interested in, you need to set the MessageSystemAttributeNames you are interested in.
